# Select median value per time range

Tags: sas, range, median

I need to select a median value for each `id`, in each age range. So in the following table, for `id = 1`, in `age_range` of 6 months, I need to select value for row 2. Basically, I need to create a column per `id` where only median for each range is selected.

```
id      wt    age_range
1       22       6
1       23       6
1       24       6
2       25       12
2       24       12
2       44       18
```

Comment: Have you looked at `proc summary` or `proc tabulate`?

Comment: I need to select the median value, of the age ranges, not compute a median..

Comment: You'll want to explain your question better then in the question.  Perhaps better format your data and show the 'want' dataset.

Comment: That's not necessarily possible. The median can be a value that never occurs in your dataset, so you need to define what you're referring to when you say 'median'. If you want the middle value, what happens with ties? Does it matter how many? What if there are multiples as in your second ID, should you take both records or one? Your question is ambiguous and you should post what you've tried per SO rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to make a new column where for each id and age_range you have the median value for comparison. You could do this in base SAS by using `proc means` to output the medians and then merge it back to the original dataset. However `proc sql` will do this all in one step and to easily name your new column.

```
proc sql data;
  create table want as
  select id, wt, age_range, median(wt) as median_wt
  from have
  group by id, age_range;
quit;


id  wt  age_range  median_wt
1   24         6          23
1   22         6          23
1   23         6          23
2   24        12        24.5
2   25        12        24.5
2   44        18          44
```

Comment: Median was added as an aggregate function in [SAS 9.4](http://support.sas.com/kb/12/133.html), might be worth mentioning in the answer.